# How do I automatically return a 404 when a GET path doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, http-status-code-404

I am using NodeJS, Express and Handlebars (template engine) to build a web application. Currently I'm trying to automatically redirect users whenever they enter an URL that does not exist (or whenever they might not have access to it).

The following returns the index page:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index/index');
});
```

But how do I make something like this:

```
router.get('/:ThisCouldBeAnything', (req, res) => {
    res.render('errors/404');
});
```

The following example is from Github:

Say that I enter this URL:

https://github.com/thispagedoesnotexist

It automatically returns a 404. How do I implement this in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use a middleware just after all route handlers to catch non existing routes:

```
app.get('/some/route', function (req, res) {
    ...
});

app.post('/some/other/route', function (req, res) {
    ...
});

...

// middleware to catch non-existing routes
app.use( function(req, res, next) {

    // you can do what ever you want here
    // for example rendering a page with '404 Not Found'
    res.status(404)
    res.render('error', { error: 'Not Found'});

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I'll be using your middleware function!

Comment: I believe I can't do that yet because I'm new here.

Comment: I did, but It states:

Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: another approach is to use `http-errors`, as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website)

Comment: Just to add that you should put this also after the routes to properly work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After all your other routes you can add:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('errors/404');
});
```

Alternately, you can use a middleware function after all your other middleware and routes.

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.render('errors/404');
});
```

So you might end up with something that looks like:

```
//body-parser, cookie-parser, and other middleware etc up here

//routes
app.get('/route1', (req, res) => {
  res.render('route1');
});

app.get('/route2', (req, res) => {
  res.render('route2');
});

//404 handling as absolute last thing
//You can use middleware
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.render('errors/404');
});

//Or a catch-all route
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('errors/404');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, YouneL. I wasn't trying to steal your answer. I must have been editing my post while you were writing yours.

Comment: Also, it looks like I posted my middleware suggestion edit a few minutes before you wrote your answer. But my more fleshed out example was posted after your answer.

Comment: No your first post was about using asterisk which is not gonna work because it match all routes

Comment: Yes, that's right. My edit where I added the middleware suggestion though, was before your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have express tagged.  All you have to do is include a default handler that includes

```
res.status(404).render('404template')
```

For example

```
app.get('*', (req, res,next) => {
     res.status(404).render('error.ejs')
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the forward slash '/', shouldn't it be a "*" like the reply above?